# SSLProxyCheckPeer directives inside <Proxy> section

Tags: apache

According to the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslproxycheckpeername) the `SSLProxyCheckPeerName` & `SSLProxyCheckPeerCN` should be allowed in the "proxy section" context; however, when I try to add them I get an error when I start apache. Any idea how I could apply these directives to a single proxy destination?

Apache config:

`<Proxy "https://1.1.1.1:1001/path">
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /path https://1.1.1.1:1001/path`

Error:

`AH00526: Syntax error on line 49 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/proxy.conf:
SSLProxyCheckPeerName not allowed here`